# domain and subdomain ssl access on plesk

Tags: ssl

I need both www.mysite.com and subdomain.mysite.com to have ssl access

I'm on PLESK/ Media temple Centos5. I have exclusive IP for mysite.com

I purchased two appropriate certificates but only www.mysite.com has ssl access.

When going to https://subdomain.mysite.com I get Error:
subdomain.mysite.com uses an invalid security certificate.The certificate is only valid for the following names:  www.mysite.com , mysite.com
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain).

On the mydomain folder in plesk I see both certificates but under 'used' column I see 1 for mydomain and 0 for subdomain.mydomain.com

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have an SSL certificate for a single IP address. You will need to give the subdomain a different IP address and a new SSL certificate tuned to that address.

There is also the option of using multiple domains on your certificate, if your CA supports this. Then you'd just create a certificate for all the domains on that IP and use that.

This might confuse some older clients and be viewed as bad style, though.

Comment: For Plesk to handle everything in a way that it likes, both sites will need their own IP.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk allows you to set up subdomains within the `mysite.com` domain page.  However, it will not allow you to change the hosting options there.  They just inherit from `mysite.com`.

Instead, you should add a new domain `subdomain.mysite.com` on it's own.  That way you can assign a different IP for the subdomain, and select the other certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a multi-subdomain SSL certificate from [gandi.net](http://www.gandi.net/ssl/standard/). This will work for all https://*.mysite.com.